# Tooltip container on tables not working / move to right site and bottom

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have added some tooltips to a table.

```
$seatplanvisualization .= '<td class="rounded seatoccupied"  data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip2" title="sdfhj asjdfh">A65</td>';
```

My problem is, when try to hover with my mouse, here on A9 it shows the tooltip on B21.
In my body, I call the tooltip like this:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip2"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' }) 
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok the fix was easy.
I had a `style="zoom:..."` in the table.
After I removed this, the tooltip is placed correctly.